# WooCommerce 'Place Order' Redirect to 404 (Sub Directory Installation)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a problem with redirection of WooCommerce '**Place Order**' button that persistently redirects to 404.

I have found out the cause of the problem is the fact that 'checkout' is not added in the URL when the place order button is clicked.

The following is the URL structure when you click the **place order** button:

http://example.com/New-Site/?key=wc_order_5b1e969783c98&order=6708

Checkout is omitted. When I manually add is as shown below; it works.

http://example.com/New-Site/checkout/?key=wc_order_5b1e969783c98&order=6708

I have this WordPress installation in a subdirectory and the htaccess is as follows :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /New-Site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /New-Site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: The two blocks in your .htaccess file are identical - you can eliminate the redundancy.  Did you set the checkout page in the WooCommerce settings in the `Advanced` tab?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sure will remove one block. Yes, I have set the checkout page in the Advanced tab.